# In Blazor - The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have upgraded .NET core from preview 7 to preview 8, and executed the following command

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview8.19405.7
```

After that, I create new blazorwasm application using Visual Studio, but the following issue occurs on building the application, Could you please suggest any solution for this issue?

**The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

Visual Stuaio version
[image]

Comment: What does `dotnet --version` return? I myself had some problems installing preview 8.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Preview 8 is not installed properly, after restarting my system it works.